# Мусор в конце строки после присваивания

Tags: c++, строки, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь разбить файл на 20 частей посимвольно. Первый массив Pack - это массив, в котором копируется текст с определенного символа, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было обрезать лишнее и получилась бы полноценная часть, что и делается во втором массиве NPack. Проблема лишь в том, что во втором массиве в каждую строку добавляется немного мусора, чаще всего это 4 символа ээээ

```
//Выделяем память под каждую часть для первого массива
char **Pack = new char*[20];
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) Pack[i] = new char[size];

for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
    strcpy(Pack[i] - col*i, fileData);
    cout << Pack[i] << endl << endl << endl;
}

//Выделяем память под каждую часть для второго массива
char **NPack = new char*[20];
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) NPack[i] = new char[col];

for (int j = 0; j<20; j++){
    if (j == 19){
        col += ost;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<col; i++){
        NPack[j][i] = Pack[j][i];
    }
    cout << NPack[j] << endl<<endl;
}

free(NPack);
free(Pack);
```

Comment: В массиве хранятся символы, а их пытаетесь обработать как си-строку. Так как си-строки должны заканчиваться нулем, то отсюдова и  все "проблемы". Либо добавляйте сознательно ноль, либо следите за длиной и работайте только с ней.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 0; j<20; j++){
    if (j == 19){
        col += ost;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<col; i++){
        NPack[j][i] = Pack[j][i];
    }
    NPack[j][col] = '\0';
    cout << NPack[j] << endl<<endl;
}
```